# How to list available ADSI (Active Directory Service Interfaces) service providers?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, directoryservices, directoryentry

How can I list available [ADSI (Active Directory Service Interfaces) service providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772235%28VS.85%29.aspx) in C#?

Comment: I understand your question now, I thought you meant which servers are providing the services, but you meant which services are provided. I don't know the answer then I'm afraid, you might want to ask on ServerFault.com if anyone there knows how to list them using a vbscript or something (since it sounds like something that sysadmins might be interested in) and if you can get a response it shouldn't be too hard to translate it to C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that:

```
foreach (object obj in (IEnumerable)Marshal.BindToMoniker("ADs:"))
{
    obj.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | 
        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
        BindingFlags.Instance | 
        BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, obj, null).Dump();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has an KB-233023 on this topic: [How To Find All ADSI Providers on a System](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/233023)

another variant:

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetAdsiProviders()
    {
        var providers = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\ADs\Providers");
        if (null == providers) yield break;

        foreach (var name in providers.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            yield return name + ":";
        }
    }
```